# Active Admin after login redirect to admin site not requested url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, activeadmin

I implemented Active admin in my rails 3.2 application.
Problem is when i request restricted resource to application its redirect me to login page but after login its redirect user to admin section of site.
i want redirect after login to requested URL.
How can i resolve this issue.
i try with below change but its not work.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  private
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    user_path(resource)
  end

end  




class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  private
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
   stored_location_for(resource) || root_path
  end

end
```

Comment: How do you determine that the requested resource is restricted? Do you  use CanCan?

Comment: yes i am using cancan

Comment: Hm... re-read your question, realized that my answar was useless.